# Shinysurveys multiple questions not loading

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a survey on shinysurveys. I have an excel file I am reading in and I believe all the columns and formatting are correct. The app launches but there are no questions appearing, just the title. Please help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinysurveys)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

df <- readxl::read_xlsx('questions.xlsx') %>% 
  group_by(question) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  ungroup()

multiQuestions <- df %>%
  mutate(page = c(
    rep(1, 2),
    rep(2, 2))
  )

multiQuestions1 <- multiQuestions %>%
  unnest(cols = data) %>% as.data.frame()

ui <- fluidPage(
    surveyOutput(df = multiQuestions1, 
                 survey_title = "the Big Crypto Personality Survey", 
                 survey_description = "xxxxx", 
                 theme = "#63B8FF"
      )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  renderSurvey()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Data looks like this

```
structure(list(question = c("What do you hold?", "What do you hold?", 
"What do you hold?", "What do you hold?", "What do you hold?", 
"What do you hold?", "What do you hold?", "What do you hold?", 
"What do you hold?", "What do you hold?", "What is your main holding?", 
"What is your main holding?", "What is your main holding?", "What is your main holding?", 
"What is your main holding?", "What is your main holding?", "What is your main holding?", 
"What is your main holding?", "What is your main holding?", "What is your main holding?", 
"What's your age ?", "Which best describes your gender?", "Which best describes your gender?", 
"Which best describes your gender?", "Which best describes your gender?"
), option = c("BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "SOL", "ADA", "XRP", "LUNA", 
"DOT", "AVAX", "DOGE", "BTC", "ETH", "BNB", "SOL", "ADA", "XRP", 
"LUNA", "DOT", "AVAX", "DOGE", "25", "Female", "Male", "Prefer not to say", 
"Prefer to self describe"), input_type = c("mc", "mc", "mc", 
"mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", 
"mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "numeric", "select", "select", 
"select", "select"), input_id = c("overall", "overall", "overall", 
"overall", "overall", "overall", "overall", "overall", "overall", 
"overall", "main", "main", "main", "main", "main", "main", "main", 
"main", "main", "main", "age", "gender", "gender", "gender", 
"gender"), dependence = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), dependence_value = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA"), required = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), page = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing sample data, e.g. by means of `dput(df)` (rather than `str(df)`), so that the code can be copy-pasted and run as is to reproduce the issue

Comment: Hi Aurele, sorry, I am new to this, first question ever asked on SO, hopeully this is how you would like the data. This is just how far i've got so far, I wanted to check that a limited version of the survey would work before expeanding it and linking it to google sheets.

Comment: The issue is with `dependence` and `dependence_value`: they should be `NA` (specifically `NA_character_`), and not `"NA"`

Comment: Thanks for your help Aurèle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Auréle mentioned, the issue is that the missing values (`NA`) are encoded as character strings (`"NA"`). I don't have a lot of experience with the readxl package, but it looks as if you can define what missing values should be encoded as NAs upon reading the questions in (see the `na` argument [here](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html#arguments)). If that doesn't work, you can always use `dplyr::mutate()` to set the dependence and depdence_value columns equal to NA as follows:

```r
# This assumes there are no dependency questions.
# If there are, you can use `case_when()` to selectively
# ensure NAs are encoded correctly.
multiQuestions1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    dependence = NA,
    dependence_value = NA
  )
```

Hope that helps! Also, I saw you might be looking to connect this survey with Google Sheets. [Here's a blog post](https://www.jdtrat.com/blog/connect-shiny-google/) I wrote to walkthrough that process.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Woohoo!